# What is "Java 6 steady state"

Tags: java, java-6

I know nothing about Java.

There is `Java 6 steady state` at benchmark

```
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php
```

which `Java 6 steady state` is the fastest among all other Java. I've searched and no good result about it

What is `Java 6 steady state`? Can any Java web framework running on `Java 6 steady state`?

Comment: To my understanding "steady state" simply means a state of the garbage collector, which must be reached for reliable benchmark results. I don't know what it actually means to be in a steady state.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to look at the [description page](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=javasteady#about). The short answer is that it runs the program 66 times, then divides the time by 66 to get an average across a large number of runs. The basic idea is that this amortizes things like <strike>JVM startup time</strike> JIT compiling across a large number of runs so you get an idea of what you could expect from something like a heavily used web service that runs all the time, so things like the <strike>JVM startup time and</strike> JIT compile time become (almost) irrelevant.

Comment: +1 - referencing the docs + explanation, always worth an upvote!

Comment: afaict the standard run time used in the benchmarks game amortizes JIT compiling (except for the very short meteor-contest run time) - but for a couple of those tiny programs the fully optimized compiled method doesn't get used until the program is run again.

Comment: good answer, though interestingly, that doesn't actually match the normal definition of "steady state" (which would exclude the startup time rather than just amortizing it...)

Comment: @mikera: as implied by the strikeouts, it actually *does* eliminate the startup time. Basically, in the "normal" tests, the startup time is amortized, but in the steady state tests, it's eliminated completely (and neither attempts to reflect what you'll see from just running a program once without a JVM loaded).

Answer (score 3):

"Java 6 steady state" refers to benchmarking the tests after all the JVM start-up, class-loading, JIT'ing, etc is done - i.e., how fast does it run once you're running it steady-state.

I'm just getting into the web-dev side of things, so I can't say for sure, but I suspect that anything running containers/servlets/whathaveyou is running at steady-state.